# Does GTK4 compiled using mingw-w64 give a memory leak when using drag and drop?

Tags: memory-leaks, gtk, mingw-w64

I'm using GTK-4 (version 4.8.2-1) with g++ on mingw-w64. I'm running Windows 11. I'm creating an app with a moveable widget and noticed that on task manager, the app rapidly eats up memory whenever a drag action is performed. Below is a minimal working example that produces this issue on my machine. Obviously this code doesn't actually do anything, but dragging the label repeatedly (on my machine, about 20 times) will cause the app to crash. Am I misunderstanding the API in some fundamental way and inadvertently causing this? Or is this an issue with GTK? mingw?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GdkContentProvider* on_drag_prepare(GtkDragSource *source, double x, double y, GtkWidget* label) {

    GValue* a = new GValue;
    (*a) = G_VALUE_INIT;
    g_value_init(a, G_TYPE_INT);
    g_value_set_int(a, 1);

    // The content is basically a single integer.
    return gdk_content_provider_new_for_value(a);
}

static void activate( GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {

    // window
    GtkWidget* window = gtk_application_window_new (app);   
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Drag Memory Leak");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 400, 400);

    // label to drag
    GtkWidget* label = gtk_label_new("Drag Me");
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW (window), label);

    // setting up drag callback
    GtkDragSource *drag_source = gtk_drag_source_new();
    gtk_drag_source_set_actions(drag_source, GDK_ACTION_MOVE);
    g_signal_connect (drag_source, "prepare", G_CALLBACK (on_drag_prepare), label);
    gtk_widget_add_controller (GTK_WIDGET (label), GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER (drag_source));

    gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int main( int argc, char **argv) {

    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);

    return status;
}
```

I expected that when I compiled and ran this program, I'd not have a memory leak when dragging a widget repeatedly.

Comment: Update: I compiled this in Ubuntu (using linux subsystem in Windows) and it produces no memory leaks. I'll try compiling on a Windows 10 machine next and see if the issues is Windows 11.